# Error:(3) error: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on my application, but I ran into an error. I have uploaded all the pictures into the drawable folder.

> Error:(3) error: not well-formed (invalid token).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/Profile"android:title="Profile" android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp" />
    <item android:id="@+id/TradingHistory"android:title="TradingHistory" android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_black_24dp" />
    <item android:id="@+id/News"android:title="News" android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp" />
</menu>
```

What does it mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: a space between android:id and android:title?  E.g android:id="@+id/Profile" android:title="Profile"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the 3<sup>rd</sup> line is not well-formed: you need a  (*blank space*) between `android:id` value and `android:title` key.

This is the correct XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/Profile" android:title="Profile" android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp" />
    <item android:id="@+id/TradingHistory" android:title="TradingHistory" android:icon="@drawable/ic_history_black_24dp" />
    <item android:id="@+id/News" android:title="News" android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to code in the toolbar  and click on reformat code.